# Enter 1 parameter for two conditions from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am putting a report on SSRS. In the query, I have multiple 'where' conditions. In one of the conditions I am checking two conditions from two different tables.

However, I want users to enter only one of the condition but it needs to be checked against the two tables.

How do I achieve that? :( See the query below.

Thank you!
Latoya

I am thinking of a case?

```
Select distinct
    ltrim(rtrim(prem_lname)) [Last Name], 
    ltrim(rtrim(prem_fname)) [First Name], 
    case when prem_act_stat = 'I' then 'Inactive' when prem_act_stat = 'A' then 'Active' when prem_act_stat = 'B' then 'Benefits Only' end [Status],
    pred_ded [Deduction Code],
    prdb_short [Deduction Description],
    case when prcc_empe_amt is not null then cast(prcc_empe_amt  as decimal (18,2)) else '' end [Employee Amount],
    case when prcc_empr_amt is not null then cast(prcc_empr_amt as decimal (18,2)) else '' end [Employer Amount]

From prempded
join prempmst on prempmst.prem_emp = prempded.pred_emp
join prdedben on prdedben.prdb_ded = prempded.pred_ded
join prempacm on prempded.pred_emp = prempacm.prcc_emp
join prpmppay on prpmppay.prpp_emp = prempmst.prem_emp
join prctlfil on prctlfil.prct_warr_key = prpmppay.prpp_warr and prpp_emp = prem_emp 

Where
    (pred_ded = '8035' and prcc_cd = '8035') and 
    prem_proj in ('0', '1','2') and
    pred_proj in ('0', '1', '2') and
    prcc_freq = 'Y' and
    prcc_year = '2018' and
    prct_chk_date >= '07-01-2018' and prct_chk_date <= '06-30-2019'

Order by [Last Name]
```

I want users to enter 1 '8035' code but it needs to meet both conditions for pred_ded and prcc_cd.

Comment: In which table is the column `prcc_cd`?

Comment: SSRS is more commonly used with sqlserver and the code looks like sqlserver (square brackets) is this in fact a sqlserver question?

Comment: prcc_cd is in the table prempacm and yes it is a sql server. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pred_ded` is in the table `prempded` and `prcc_cd` is in the table `prempacm` and you want them to be equal, in the join of the tables:

```
join prempacm on prempded.pred_emp = prempacm.prcc_emp
```

add one more condition:

```
join prempacm on prempded.pred_emp = prempacm.prcc_emp and prempded.pred_ded = prempacm.prcc_cd
```

and in the `where` clause leave only:

```
Where
    prempded.pred_ded = '8035' 
    ..................
```

Comment: Well silly me didn't think of that! Ha! So simple! Thank you so much!!! :D